# Cannot connect to Laravel server in Virtual Box appliance

Tags: php, networking, laravel, debian, virtualbox

I am trying to implement my first Rest API using Laravel.

I am running Debian on a Virtual Box machine on a Windows host. The network card of the VM is configured to "Host-only adapter".

I am able to reach the phpmyadmin instance on the machine using `http://ip-of-the-vm/phpmyadmin`. But when I try to reach the Laravel appliance on `http://ip-of-the-vm:8000` it does not work. I think the port could be the problem.

Does anybody have a suggestion for how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that laravel was only reachable over localhost. You have to start the server using 
`php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` where `0.0.0.0` should be replaced with the ip of the server.
You can optionally define a port if you want by using
`php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80` for example.