# How to enter a php artisan serve linux in windows?

Tags: laravel, centos

I am trying to run a laravel project on a linux server to test the app, but I have a problem, I usually use windows and it is enough using the command `php artisan serve --host = 192.168.0.1` and all normal I use it in local area and it works wonderfully, but I need it to run on a linux server, for this install in a virtual machine, centos 7 (minimum requirements), perform the corresponding installations, pass my project, clear the cache, the views , check if there was ping between both virtual and physical machines,

I use the `php artisan serve --host = 192.160.0.1` but when I try to enter the page it keeps loading and tells me that the waiting time is up and if I use the local `127.0.0.1` tells me that the connection has been rejected. How can i fix this? I thank you in advance.
As additional data, the apache server if it is running normally, on both computers you can ping their addresses.

Comment: `php artisan serve` should only be used for local development, you should look into using apache or nginx for hosting your laravel project: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment#nginx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068292/3256489